# crunchy data pgo backrest in pending state in Kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, pgo

I'm deploying pgo in Kubernetes by following this link:
https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/postgres-operator/latest/quickstart/
after trying it on minikube successfully.
After running the command

```
pgo create cluster -n pgo hippo
kubectl get pods -n pgo
```

I get the fllowing result:

```
NAME                                         READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
hippo-backrest-shared-repo-8ddd75f69-f4jfj   0/1     Pending     0          3s
pgo-deploy-tzw2v                             0/1     Completed   0          17m
postgres-operator-797bcb5d6-mjwxq            4/4     Running     0          15m
```

If I run:

```
kubectl describe pods hippo-backrest-shared-repo-8ddd75f69-f4jfj -n pgo
Name:           hippo-backrest-shared-repo-8ddd75f69-f4jfj
Namespace:      pgo
Priority:       0
Node:           <none>
Labels:         name=hippo-backrest-shared-repo
                pg-cluster=hippo
                pg-pod-anti-affinity=preferred
                pgo-backrest-repo=true
                pod-template-hash=8ddd75f69
                service-name=hippo-backrest-shared-repo
                vendor=crunchydata
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:             
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/hippo-backrest-shared-repo-8ddd75f69
Containers:
  database:
    Image:      registry.developers.crunchydata.com/crunchydata/crunchy-pgbackrest-repo:centos8-13.1-4.6.0
    Port:       2022/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Requests:
      memory:  48Mi
    Environment:
      MODE:                        pgbackrest-repo
      PGBACKREST_STANZA:           db
      PGBACKREST_DB_PATH:          /pgdata/hippo
      PGBACKREST_REPO1_PATH:       /backrestrepo/hippo-backrest-shared-repo
      PGBACKREST_PG1_PORT:         5432
      PGBACKREST_LOG_PATH:         /tmp
      PGBACKREST_PG1_SOCKET_PATH:  /tmp
      PGBACKREST_DB_HOST:          hippo
    Mounts:
      /backrestrepo from backrestrepo (rw)
      /etc/pgbackrest/conf.d from pgbackrest-config (rw)
      /sshd from sshd (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False 
Volumes:
  sshd:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  hippo-backrest-repo-config
    Optional:    false
  backrestrepo:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  hippo-pgbr-repo
    ReadOnly:   false
  pgbackrest-config:
    Type:                Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    ConfigMapName:       hippo-config-backrest
    ConfigMapOptional:   0xc00090a479
    SecretName:          hippo-config-backrest
    SecretOptionalName:  0xc00090a47a
QoS Class:               Burstable
Node-Selectors:          <none>
Tolerations:             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                         node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                 ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  43s (x4 over 2m44s)  default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.
```

I have also create a default storage class with:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

```
ubuntu@master-node:~$ kubectl get storageclass
NAME                 PROVISIONER                    RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE   ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
standard (default)   kubernetes.io/no-provisioner   Delete          Immediate           false                  84m
```

PVC:

```
ubuntu@master-node:~$ kubectl get pvc -n pgo
NAME              STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
hippo             Pending                                      standard       12m
hippo-pgbr-repo   Pending                                      standard       12m

ubuntu@master-node:~$ kubectl describe pvc hippo -n pgo
Name:          hippo
Namespace:     pgo
StorageClass:  standard
Status:        Pending
Volume:        
Labels:        pg-cluster=hippo
               pgremove=true
               vendor=crunchydata
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      
Access Modes:  
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason              Age                   From                         Message
  ----     ------              ----                  ----                         -------
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed  3m54s (x42 over 14m)  persistentvolume-controller  no volume plugin matched name: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner


ubuntu@master-node:~$ kubectl describe pvc hippo-pgbr-repo -n pgo
Name:          hippo-pgbr-repo
Namespace:     pgo
StorageClass:  standard
Status:        Pending
Volume:        
Labels:        pg-cluster=hippo
               pgremove=true
               vendor=crunchydata
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      
Access Modes:  
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       hippo-backrest-shared-repo-8ddd75f69-f4jfj
Events:
  Type     Reason              Age                   From                         Message
  ----     ------              ----                  ----                         -------
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed  4m22s (x42 over 14m)  persistentvolume-controller  no volume plugin matched name: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
```

How can i solve it and properly create a correct PersistenVolumeClaims and pass to pgo? I am available for further clarifications or informations.
Thanks.

EDIT:

```
ubuntu@master-node:~$ kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
local-volume-provisioner-s6cnm   1/1     Running   0          3m21s

ubuntu@master-node:~$ kubectl get pv -n pgo
NAME                 CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS        CLAIM                       STORAGECLASS    REASON   AGE
task-pv-pgo          100Gi      RWO            Delete           Available                                 local-storage            3m44s
```

Comment: Can you describe the PVC? Maybe include `kubectl get events -n pgo`?

Comment: @SYN sure, I have edit the question. Adding the describe pvc results.

Comment: i have take "kubernetes.io/no-provisioner" from here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#local

Comment: Then you need to provision local volumes, see: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local

Comment: Apparently, you may also use some volumes provisioner: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-local-static-provisioner

Comment: ok, now i have a local-volume-provisioner pod up and running, i also have create a pv using the yaml file i found in the link, but nothing change. I have edit the question.

Comment: Create pgo/hippo pvc with local-storage storageClass